# ssrs Matrix without title for the value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

How can i get the name of my column value in title

**here is what i do**

[image: Tablix]

**here is what i got**
[image]

**and here is what i want**
[image]

don't look at the value, it's just random .
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on any of the cells in the detail row, for example the one that starts with the expression `[Sum(Cout_MO...` then choose

[image]

Then choose "Insert Row"-->"Outside Group - Above"

Then just type the column headers in

Comment: Thank you :) i knew it was easy, but i didn't know it was that easy